# How to parcel custom list on Android?

Tags: android, serialization

First of all, all the code i will refer to is at [my repository](https://github.com/Drknzz/MachinaEx)

I have been having problems parcelizing a [PlayList](https://github.com/Drknzz/MachinaEX/blob/master/MachinaEx/src/com/machinarius/music/data/PlayList.java), the parcelizing works wonders but the deserializing ends up on either a NullPointerException or a BadParcelableException. I haven't been able to pinpoint the source of the exceptions, thus i ask you to check my code to see if i'm abusing any OOP principles or outright misusing the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the all the class as a parameter to `parcel.write()`. You need to pass just the parameter `copy` received in the constructor. You also need to ensure that all objects manipulated are or implement ´Parcelable`.

I believe you need to change the follwing:

**In constructor**

```
ArrayList<Song> copy;

public PlayList(ArrayList<Song> copy){
  super(copy);  
  this.copy = copy;
}
```

**In write()**

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeTypedList(copy);
    parcel.writeInt(actualSong);
    parcel.writeInt(shuffling ? 1 : 0);
    parcel.writeInt(repeating ? 1 : 0);
}
```

**In read()**

```
public PlayList(Parcel serialized) {
    super(serialized.readTypedList(copy, Song.WptType.CREATOR));
    actualSong = serialized.readInt();
    shuffling = serialized.readInt() == 1 ? true : false;
    repeating = serialized.readInt() == 1 ? true : false;
}
```

**NOTE**

You also need to implement `Parcelable` in the `Song` class for this to work, but it looks already done in the code repository.